# Open Ax client from external application

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

Is it possible to open an AX client from an external application, for instance a c# console application.

I've tried to open the AX client by using the -StartupCmd=AutoRun_MyConfig.xml command.

The Xml-file uses the Run command to open a class I've created but I cannot get it to work for a regular user, only for system administrators. Is this a limitation in AX?

Run type=\"class\" name=\"{0}\" method=\"{1}\" parameters=\"{2}\" />

Do you have any other idea on how I can proceed or an alternative solution?

br, Johan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just start the ax32.exe with the [proper parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa569653.aspx).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906078/dynamics-ax-2009-client-config-file-start-path-problem).

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21315939/4509) on how to tickle the drill-down code to start an arbitrary menu item.

Comment: I've tried to start AX with the parameter by passing the startupCmd parameter but AX doesn't execute the class I've created unless the user is a system admin...

Comment: `startupCmd` is not ment to be used by mortals, only admins.

Comment: haha I was afraid that was the case :\ what other possible solution do I have left?

Comment: See part 3 of my answer. This requires a code modification and AX client installation on each computer using it.

Comment: I see, I'll look into the drilldown-solution. Thank you